# laravel Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: php, laravel

```
{
    $form = new Form(new ProductScheme);
    $products = Product::where('status', 1)->get();

    $options = [];
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $options[$product->id] = $product->name . ' - ' . $product->code;
    }

    $form->multipleSelect('product_id', 'Select Product')
        ->options($options);

    $form->date('start_date');
    $form->date('end_date');
    $form->textarea('description', __('Description'));

  $form->saving(function (Form $form) {
            $productIds = $form->product_id ?: [];
            $filteredProductIds = array_filter($productIds);

            foreach ($filteredProductIds as $fkey => $productId) {
                $productScheme = new ProductScheme;
                $productScheme->product_id = $productId;
                $productScheme->decription = $form->decription;
                $productScheme->start_date = $form->start_date;
                $productScheme->end_date = $form->end_date;
                $productScheme->save();
            }

        });
    return $form;
}


<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class ProductScheme extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'product_scheme';
    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'decription', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $hidden = [];
    protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    protected $casts = [];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $attributes = [];

     public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

   

}
```

here ia using https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin
TypeError In Grammar.php line 136 :

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called invendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 884 how solve this error. and what is the proble?[2023-07-04 23:14:45] production.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 884 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 884 at /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php:136)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(884): Illuminate\Database\Grammar->parameterize('2023-07-04')
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\{closure}('2023-07-04', 'start_date')
#2 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(638): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#3 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(885): Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Object(Closure))
#4 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php(135): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->compileInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), Array)
#5 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php(914): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar->compileInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), Array)
#6 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2835): Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->compileInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), Array, 'id')
#7 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1422): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#8 /home/yhzt6oyvfkqx/public_html//vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(902): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)

Comment: That "Stacktrace" (the error message) should show the non-vendor code that is triggering this error. Look closely at the error in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file when this error is triggered and see if you can find the line in **your** code that triggers this. I don't see anything obvious, so it's possible (and likely) that you've got something misconfigured which, when triggering Laravel code, triggers this error.